# Python match case: continue to match next case even matched?

Tags: python

```py
key: Literal['all', 'a', 'b'] = 'a'

def do_a():
    pass
def do_b():
    pass

match key:
    case 'a':
        do_a()
    case 'b':
        do_b()
    case 'all':
        do_a()
        do_b()
```

Is there any way to simplify the code so I can remove the `case 'all'`?

Something like

```py
match key:
    case 'a' | 'all':
        do_a()
    case 'b' | 'all':
        do_b()
```

Comment: why dont you use if, elif, else? And why would it be "simpler", it is shorter true, but not simpler, rather the opposite.

Comment: The example is just a demo. There could be more value types, like `'group1', 'a', 'b', 'c'` and `'group2', 'd', 'e', 'f'`.

Comment: `if/elif` is the way to go here. It's barely any longer than the indented solution. Your code is not what match case (or, as it's officially called **structural pattern matching**, which is not happening here) is desgined for in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Setup:

```
from typing import Literal
key: Literal['all', 'a', 'b']

def do_a():
    print('do_a')
    
def do_b():
    print('do_b')
```

---

**Solution I:** You can just use `if`:

```
if key in ('a', 'all'):
    do_a()
if key in ('b',  'all'):
    do_b()
```

---

**Solution II:** You could use a function mapper, like so:

```
function_mapper = {
    'all': (do_a, do_b),
    'a': (do_a,),
    'b': (do_a,),
}

key = 'all'
for func in function_mapper[key]:
    func()
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=match#match-statements):

> Only the first pattern that matches gets executed[.]

According to the [official Python documentation (PEP 636)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0636/),

> once the first matching pattern is found, the body of that case is executed, and all further cases are ignored.

Therefore, C-style fall-through matching (using `switch` with `case`s that lack `break;`) is not possible with Python's `match` statement syntax.

Being creative with disjunctive patterns (like you suggest) gets you there part of the way, but I believe it doesn't help in this particular case, since you want both `do_a()` and `do_b()` executed in the case of `'all'`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do so if you don't use if/elif. As others said, with 'if' you can have:

```
if key in ('a', 'all'): # tuple is faster than list
    do_a()
if key in ('b', 'all'):
    do_b()
```

Code below will only return do_a() and do_b() won't be executed.

```
match key:
    case 'a' | 'all':
        do_a() # will only return do_a()
    case 'b' | 'all':
        do_b()
```

Comment: That's not what OP wanted. He wants both do_a and do_b to be executed. And you just copypasted the code from his answer

Comment: @matszwecja thanks, I just added the solution...learning to answer posts